# Default credentials for Cisco SNMPv3

Tags: cisco, snmp

I was wondering of SNMPv3 is enabled by default on Cisco devices and if there are default credentials?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to enable snmp on cisco devices and add users that are allowed to use it.
Information on how to do this and troubleshooting commands can be found on the cisco website [here](http://www.cisco.com/en/US/docs/ios/12_0t/12_0t3/feature/guide/Snmp3.html#wp18886)

Edit: another site where you can find usefull config examples is [here](https://web.archive.org/web/20181229220850/http://docwiki.cisco.com/wiki/Snmp_v3_configurations)